# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Uri to string

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to set the `Text` property of a `TextBox` to the `Url` property of a `WebBrowser`. The code I have is:

```
textBox1.Text = webBrowser1.Url;
```

Visual Studio says:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Uri to string"

How do I set the `textBox1.Text` property to the value of the `webBrowser1.Url`?

Comment: There are no attributes in the code shown... Are you sure you were planning to ask about attributes and not about properties for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to call the `ToString` method:

```
textBox1.Text = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks! That really helped!

Comment: Now I'm stuck the other way. I have:    webBrowser1.Url = "http://www.google.com";     and am trying to set the url to the string, but I get the same error. "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Uri to string"

Comment: Do you understand what the message means? the `Url` property of a `WebBrowser` is of type `Uri` (not `string`). So you have to pass it a `Uri`. The message is telling you this...that it can't automatically convert a `string` to a `Uri`, so that means you have to do it. Look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492(v=vs.110).aspx) for a `Uri` and see how to create one from a `string`. Then use the `Uri` that you create as the right hand side of your `webBrowser1.Url` assignment. Also, please mark an answer to your original question if it's resolved! :)

Answer (score 1):

The `webBrowser1.Url` is of `type` `System.Uri`. To assign it to textbox, which is of`type` `string` you can simply do a `webBrowser1.Url.ToString()` or use in-built properties like `AbsoluteUri`, `OriginalString` etc. depending on your requirement. For complete list of properties refer this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) link.